# New logstash grok config affect old log data

Tags: logstash

I've added new grok config for logstash. But it only have effect on the data after this config. How can I make it process the log data before the config time?

Comment: You'll have to reindex your data with the new Logstash configuration. How to do that depends on how you indexed your data the first time, so you'll have to provide more information, such as your input configuration

Comment: I've add grok config in logstash filter. Here is the config below:                         ```grok {
        patterns_dir => "/mnt/deploy/logstash/pattern"
        match => {
          "msg" => "%{DLCMALEIDENTITY}"
        }
       add_field => [ "sex", "male" ]
    }```  So after this config, the new message will be parsed with some new filed `sex`. But before this time, same message can't have the `sex` field

Comment: I understood that part of your problem. You have to delete all the data from before the config change and filter it again